# Why do computers use binary, instead of ternary, or some other logic system?

Tags: efficiency, storage

In binary a unit (bit), can store 2 separate values.

if you have ternary, then a unit can store 3 separate values.

why then don't computers use higher bases, for example in ternary you could have 3 different voltages, and even if transistors got a little bigger, wouldn't it still be more efficient?

Answer (score 2):

- 3 different voltage levels makes building circuits harder and it is easier for little errors to occur in the signals.
- Circuits need complex logic instead of the easy boolean logic which works perfectly.
- Ternary is not compatible with binary that all computers use.